# Access Linux VM from Windows via SSH

Tags: ssh, unix, virtual-machine, putty, azure

I am running out of ideas on what exactly I need to do to get into the unix vm hosted in Azure.

How to access Linux VM from Windows 7 using Putty or similar SSH client.

Information I have been provided is: 
1) IP address of Virtual Machine. 
2) The Unix machine which only allows SSH key logins and no password. 
3) Username. 
4) Password to unlock ssh key.

I downloaded putty but I am not a Unix guy so can't figure out what steps I need to get access to the unix machine.

Thanks

Comment: You have the ssh key downloaded to the Win 7 install?  if not  do so as your putty session will need to have access to it in order to connect to the VM. the private (aka secret part) of that  ssh key should be on the Azure  client you will have the public,  once both are  seen during authentication you will be  golden.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-classic-remote-desktop/)?

Comment: Well issue is I dont have access to Unix VM to get into it to even setup xrdp.

Answer (score 0):

Historical question. But this is what people do.

1. Access the portal at https://portal.azure.com/#home.
2. Find your "Network Security Group" and add your (client IP) IP for port 22.
3. Make a note of the public IP - if it changes often-consider dynamic IP providers.
4. You should have half of the keypair in a .pem file.
5. Convert this to a .ppk file - See PuTTY support.
6. Create a definition in PuTTY, go into Connection, SSH, Auth and enter the .ppk file details.
7. Have a go. Refine fonts and character encoding later.
8. Windows 10 has SSH from the command line, including SCP.

You should be good to go. Note that 2. is required every time if your client's public IP address changes. You can automate this with API scripts later. Don't just leave it open for everybody. I advise against password only authentication.

The Azure shell access from the web was not crash hot when this question was asked.